Why doesn't Python put the iterator class in __mro__, when using map.__mro__, but it considers map a subclass of iterator?
I dont understand why in python when i write:
from collections.abc import *
  print(map.__mro__)
  print(issubclass(map,Iterator))

The output I get is:
(<class 'map'>, <class 'object'>)
True
but the iterator class is not displayed in the return of map.___mro___, why does that happen? It is related on how mro works?
I expected that "class Iterator" appeared in the console when i wrote print(map.___mro___)

“abc” = abstract base class

@Ry- What is your point? issubclass(map, collections.abc.Sequence) is False, for example.

@Selcuk I believe the point is that that these abc's implement virtual subclassing, as described in the link.

@Selcuk: Well, a map isn’t a Sequence, so I’m not sure what you mean by that. And yes, what juanpa.arrivillaga said.

This is because collections.abc.Iterator implements a __subclasshook__ method that considers a given class to be its subclass as long as it has the __iter__ and __next__ methods defined:
class Iterator(Iterable):

    __slots__ = ()

    @abstractmethod
    def __next__(self):
        'Return the next item from the iterator. When exhausted, raise StopIteration'
        raise StopIteration

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is Iterator:
            return _check_methods(C, '__iter__', '__next__')
        return NotImplemented

